# Prevent Select query with Exists condition to reevaluate each time

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, jet

We have a SQL query that is run using the JET db engine against an Access DB. Unfortunately we are unable to create any stored procedures or move to SQL Server, which would be my preference. [Facepalm].

The problem is that the query is extremely slow. It takes around 2 minutes to process the request and we have to perform this on 4 different tables so its 8 minutes of processing. When we run each select statement independently, they will take 1-2 seconds. It's when we put them together and use the EXISTS clause that it slows down. We have a DB with two tables, first table is roughly 3000 rows and the second has roughly 5000 rows. We want to select all rows in the first table where a value (FieldName) exists in the string of another table. We do not need any fields from the second table, only to know the FieldName exists somewhere in the VBScript column. I believe with the way this is written, it is performing a query against the entire second table for each row (3000 * 5000). Is there anyway to change this query so that is does not perform that many lookups?

```
SELECT A1.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM tblEncompasstoCB CB
     WHERE ((NOT CB.VBScript IS NULL) AND (CB.VBScript <> ''))) AS A1
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblMapping
            WHERE (tblMapping.VBScript <> '')
              AND (InStr(tblMapping.VBScript, IIF(INSTR(A1.FieldName, '~') > 0, MID(A1.FieldName, 1, INSTR(A1.FieldName, '~') - 1), A1.FieldName)) > 0))
    OR
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblCustomMapping
            WHERE (tblCustomMapping.VBScript <> '')
              AND (InStr(tblCustomMapping.VBScript, IIF(INSTR(A1.FieldName, '~') > 0, MID(A1.FieldName, 1, INSTR(A1.FieldName, '~') - 1), A1.FieldName)) > 0))
```

Comment: If you can't change your underlying architecture and your records dose not grow and still maximum 5000, you can load the data into memory and query theme using Linq.

Comment: you could probably do this with cross join but whenever you see InStr in query its almost certainly bad design.

Comment: This is pretty hopeless for performance improvement, because the keys don't match between the tables.

Comment: I think a minor gain is moving IIF(INSTR(A1.FieldName, '~') > 0, MID(A1.FieldName, 1, INSTR(A1.FieldName, '~') - 1), A1.FieldName) as a field in the initial select and giving it a name. (optimizing 101 - move things to the outer "loops") my 2c

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what takes 1-2 seconds? We cannot see what you see. Post the queries!

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea, I meant running each select statement. There are three select statements in this total query, if you run each one just to see the results, it is fast as expected.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik, we are trying to utilize a quick change in the SQL, not the underlying c# code that calls on this using JET. Your suggestion is changing the code and if we went that route, we would change the architecture and DB as well. Thank you though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, we were thinking the same, these tables were not meant for this specific query. It came out of necessity years after their original creation. I was just hoping there was something we were missing. I guess not. It will just be slow. :/ Thank you.

Comment: The subqueries are *correlated* to `A1`, so the **have** to be evaluated repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Use only SELECT TOP 1 in exists

Comment: With any reasonable database, an EXISTS subquery will already stop executing as soon as a matching row is found so that's not needed. (OTOH, OP *is* using Access...)

Comment: Yes, we are using EXISTS with the expectation that it would stop execution when it finds the first results.